# How to speed up Gensim Word2vec model by filtering out some words?

Tags: word2vec

Suppose I filter in a list the word that i want to use in my next word2vec model load. How can I construct my own KeyedVectors that contain only these filtered words list?

I tried to make:

```
w2v_model_keyed = w2v_model.wv
w2v_model_keyed.drop(word)
```

for a given word but i get the following error:

```
 AttributeError: 'KeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'drop'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The gensim `KeyedVectors` class doesn't support incremental expansion or modification (as with a `.drop()` method). You'll need to construct a new instance, of just the right size/contents.

You should look the gensim [`KeyedVectors` source code](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py), and especially the [`.load_word2vec_format()` method](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/29968840f350746647f0b0e7c880d9d3866c5522/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L156), to learn how existing instances are created in gensim, and mimic that to create one that is of just the size/words you need.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 4.1.2, Gensim  [KeyedVectors](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html) object supports method [.vectors_for_all](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.vectors_for_all) that takes a list of words and creates a new KeyedVectors object with the corresponding vectors for those words only.

```py
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("model.bin", binary=True)
words_to_keep = ["salmon", "tuna", "cod"]
smaller_model = model.vectors_for_all(words_to_keep)
smaller_model.save_word2vec_format("smaller_model.bin", binary=True)
```